# .NET Web API + MySQL: Issues with POST/PUT methods asking for too many parameters and GET method not giving binded entities

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi

As a beginner in .Net and in api development, I encountered an issue recently.

My API is linked to a MySQL database but it seems that I may have not set it up correctly.

For example, I have these tables: 'user' and 'profession'.

One user can have one profession but many users could share the same profession.

I followed a tutorial on Youtube to link my api to the database and I managed it for the methods GET, GETById and DELETE only.

The first issue I get is that when I use the GET method for one entity of the database, the api only returns data about this entity and not the one it is binded to. For example, if i try to get the users, I don't have any information about the users' professions:

```
  {
    "idUser": 1,
    "userProfessionId": 1,
    "userProfessionFieldId": 1,
    "userName": "user_test",
    "userMail": "mail@test.com",
    "userCompany": "TestCompany",
    "userPicture": null,
    "userProfession": null,
    "userProfessionField": null,
    "dataUsages": []
  }
```

In the database, both the profession_id and the profession_idfield_id, which are foreign keys to other tables, are worth '1'.

This is my GET method:

```
        // GET: api/Users
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetUsers()
{
    return await _context.Users.ToListAsync();
}
```

How can I display information about the profession instead of having a 'null' value ?

My second issue happens when I want to post an user for example.

I have to fill every information of the binded tables as for example:

```
{
  "idUser": 0,
  "userProfessionId": 0,
  "userProfessionFieldId": 0,
  "userName": "string",
  "userMail": "string",
  "userCompany": "string",
  "userPicture": "string",
  "userProfession": {
    "idProfession": 0,
    "professionName": "string",
    "professionFields": [
      {
        "idProfessionField": 0,
        "professionFieldName": "string",
        "professionId": 0,
        "profession": "string",
        "users": [
          "string"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "users": [
      "string"
    ]
  },
  "userProfessionField": {
    "idProfessionField": 0,
    "professionFieldName": "string",
    "professionId": 0,
    "profession": "string",
    "users": [
      "string"
    ]
  },
  "dataUsages": [
    {
      "idDataUsage": 0,
      "openDataId": 0,
      "dateOfUsage": "2022-09-30T11:48:02.777Z",
      "dataFormatId": 0,
      "languageId": 0,
      "isDownloaded": 0,
      "usedBy": 0,
      "dataFormat": {
        "idDataFormat": 0,
        "dataFormatName": "string",
        "dataUsages": [
          "string"
        ]
      },
      "language": {
        "idDataLanguage": 0,
        "dataLanguageName": "string",
        "dataUsages": [
          "string"
        ]
      },
      "openData": {
        "idData": 0,
        "dataUrl": "string",
        "dataOpenLicense": 0,
        "dataOwnerId": 0,
        "updateFrequencyId": 0,
        "dataThemeId": 0,
        "dataOwner": {
          "idDataOwner": 0,
          "dataOwnerName": "string",
          "openData": [
            "string"
          ]
        },
        "dataTheme": {
          "idDataTheme": 0,
          "dataThemeName": "string",
          "openData": [
            "string"
          ]
        },
        "updateFrequency": {
          "idUpdateFrequency": 0,
          "updateFrequencyName": "string",
          "openData": [
            "string"
          ]
        },
        "dataUsages": [
          "string"
        ]
      },
      "usedByNavigation": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know much about this subject but it doesn't feel like it should be working this way.
My models for both 'user' and 'profession' have been generated by EntitytFramework after having linked the database.

Those are my models for both 'user' and 'profession':

```
namespace Sims.Models
{
    public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            DataUsages = new HashSet<DataUsage>();
        }

        public long IdUser { get; set; }
        public int UserProfessionId { get; set; }
        public int UserProfessionFieldId { get; set; }
        public string? UserName { get; set; }
        public string? UserMail { get; set; }
        public string? UserCompany { get; set; }
        public byte[]? UserPicture { get; set; }

        public virtual Profession UserProfession { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual ProfessionField UserProfessionField { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual ICollection<DataUsage> DataUsages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace Sims.Models
{
    public partial class Profession
    {
        public Profession()
        {
            ProfessionFields = new HashSet<ProfessionField>();
            Users = new HashSet<User>();
        }

        public int IdProfession { get; set; }
        public string ProfessionName { get; set; } = null!;

        public virtual ICollection<ProfessionField> ProfessionFields { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Maybe this is all usual but as I'm a beginner learning by myself, I do not want to be mistaken.

Thanks for reading ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `.ToListAsync()` with related entities that are `virtual`, you have to explicitely tell entity framework to include those related entities:

```
return await _context.Users.Include(u => u.UserProfession).ToListAsync();
```

Also, in your example, this approach might lead to an object cycle that will likely throw a JsonException. This can be avoided by changing the JsonSerializerOptions for your project or only querying for relevant data:

```
return await context.Users
    .Select(u => new 
    { 
        u.IdUser,
        u.UserName,
        u.UserMail,
        u.UserCompany,
        u.UserProfessionId,
        UserProfessionName = u.UserProfession.ProfessionName,
     })
     .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering !

Concerning the first solution you were right for the exception about object cycle.



Concercning the second solution, I get an error stating that "Cannot implicitly convert anonymous type to Models.User". Is the code wrong ? [link to code](https://pastebin.com/Ve9bCDhG)

Comment: This is likely a result of the return type `Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>>` of `GetUsers()` in the example you provided.

Comment: You could either just return a generic `ActionResult` without any type parameters, or use a DTO class instead that only contains the necessary information you would like to provide in this controller.  For the second approach, depending on the size of your application, you might also want to consider using a mapper library so you don't have to copy each property manually.